Is coconut oil the most saturated plant-based oil?
Looking through the oils that can be used to make soaps on LyeCalc.com, I saw that coconut oil has a very high saturated fat content: 77%! Cow butterfat is comprised of only 53% saturated fat.
Is coconut oil the most saturated plant-based oil?

It looks like that may be the case, but I can't find a direct reference. It looks like palm oil is the next closest at around 50% saturated fat.
